# Groups of workspaces in XMonad

Tags: xmonad

I've modified my XMonad config to add additional workspaces, each corresponding to a keyboard key, but I've run out of keys which are easily reachable from the home row finger resting position.
Can I have groups of workspaces?

For an example use case, assuming state-machine semantics for the workspace groups, I might do `Mod-G-1` to enter `Group 1`, then do `Mod-1` to enter `(Group 1).(Workspace 1)`.
Later, I might do `Mod-G-2` to enter `Group 2`, then do `Mod-1` to enter `(Group 2).(Workspace 1)`.

I'm guessing it wouldn't be too hard to code this myself, but I'd rather use an existing solution if one is available.

And yes, I do need all those workspaces.